# Using properties from internal and external campaigns in a report

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to generate a report comparing conversions from external sources (via an external campaign) vs conversions from internal sources (such as the content marketing section of a site).

For example:

- An external campaign uses: `utm_source=newsletter`, `utm_medium=newsletter` `utm_campaign=dec newsletter`.
- An internal campaign uses: `internal_source=content`.

As I understand, internal campaigns must not use UTM params. So then how is it possible to build a report which has conversions % in one column and a source (could be internal or external) in the other column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Custom Dimensions. You would want to create a session level custom dimension that captures the value from the url string with the query key `utm_campaign` and `internal_source`.

From there, you can create a custom report with the dimension set to your custom dimension, and the metric set to Conversion Rate.

This also means that the most recent campaign (e.g. a user clicked on an external campaign, then an internal campaign, will be captured. This means that you can use 'Campaign' as a secondary dimension to evaluate the total number of users who entered through a external campaign and clicked on an internal campaign.

Comment: I've made a slight edit to your answer above. To confirm the custom dimension (lets call it `effective_campaigns` for example) would capture the `internal_source` param if present, if not then it would capture the `utm_campaign` in the param. Is that right?

Comment: Partially, I am assuming that the UTM campaign and the Internal Source would be available at different times? e.g. On landing page UTM is present, then if a user clicks on internal marketing, that is now present in the url and the utm_campaign is no longer. By sending both to the same custom dimension (at sesison level), the most recent value will be the one that 'sticks' for the session. This means that the most recent source interaction (whether UTM_campaign or internal_source) will be the value for the custom dimension.

Comment: I see. So if I were to use a common custom dimension to represent `utm_campaign` if present else the `internal_source` then I would need to figure out a way to set this session/user level custom dimension only once. I wonder if there is a way in GA to do it or if it would need custom code on my end. I realize this might be a different question. I've asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083232/set-custom-dimension-value-only-once